# Pattern rule for prerequisite regardless of target

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a Makefile where I use the `Rscript` command to make a variety of different targets using R scripts.

```
object.rds: script1.R
    Rscript $<

target.csv: script2.R
    Rscript $<

another.rds: script3.R target.csv object.rds
    Rscript $<
```

Is there a way to define a universal rule such that any recipe with a file matching the `%.R` pattern as the first prerequisite always runs `Rscript $<`? For instance, something like:

```
**: %.R **
    Rscript $<
```

I guess the thing I'm looking for is the *inverse* of a last resort rule -- i.e. a recipe with an arbitrary target but a specific prerequisite (or, at least, one based on a pattern).

(Note that this is not specific to R -- I could ask the exact same question with python, ruby, bash, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Pattern rules need to match a *pattern*, if your target filenames have no connection to the Rscript filename you might as well just provide a single recipe for the three targets and specify the dependencies separately

```
object.rds: script1.R
target.csv: script2.R
another.rds: script3.R target.csv object.rds

object.rds target.csv another.rds:
    Rscript $<
```

Comment: Cool! So presumably, if I had a large list of targets that I didn't want to enumerate individually, I could replace the last two lines with something like: `%: ; Rscript $<`? Or a default rule -- `%:: ; Rscript $<`?

Comment: @AlexeyShiklomanov You could, sure, but match-anything rules are brittle and unpredictable, is it really all that hard to just spell the targets out?

Answer (score 0):

You could create an intermediate target:

```
 %.R_run: %.R
      Rscript $<

 object.rds: script1.R_run

 target.csv: script2.R_run

 another.rds: script3.R_run target.csv object.rds
```

Such that `object.rds` depends on `script1.R` having been run.